# Hardcore vim mode: what is the best way to move vertically?

Tags: vim

I have started using vim a while back and have been jumping with my right hand on and off "home row".  As I learned more about efficient navigation, using "f,t" and "F,T" became my favourite way to navigate within the row, i.e. horizontally.  It is so convenient that i started considering "hardcore vim" mode where the homerow navigation is turned off altogether.

My question is, what would be the high precision vertical navigation approach in "hardcore vim" mode.  Move up one line, move down one line. Few key strokes to position your cursor exactly on a line without knowing or caring about the line number.

Thanks!

P.S. I do know about moving per paragraph, enclosing brackets, but somehow i miss the type of precision that horizontal navigation has.

**After a bit of research:**

[This link](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/528/move-vertically-to-a-specific-character-on-a-different-line) on the [dedicated vim stack overflow website](http://vi.stackexchange.com/) seems to be very close to what i am asking.  Although the accepted answer doesn't quite fit the bill for me, it contains a link to [EasyMotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) plugin, that could help to speed up navigation without using the homerow.  Downside being having to install a plugin vs. using raw vim.

Thank you all for your comments and answers, too bad i cannot upvote just yet.

Comment: Matter of preference. You can use relative jumps like `5j` or `5k` to go down or up 5 lines, respectively. You could use a quick-jump plugin like [easymotion](https://github.com/easymotion/vim-easymotion) for higher precision jumps while still being very quick.

Comment: Using homerow navigation is not an option! :-)

Comment: Then I am confused what you're asking. Also this is not a programming question so you will probably start to collect close votes. You may have better luck asking this on [the vi site](http://vi.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What is homerow navigation to you? and ftr. - I usually either keep j or k pressed or initiate a search `/` or `?`to get to where I want.

Comment: I am sorry but i don't know how to phrase it better.   And you are right, probably it is the wrong venue for this type of question.  Sorry about it.

Comment: Homerow is hjkl, the equivalent to arrow keys

Comment: This question is more in line with the following [blog post](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/02/habit-breaking-habit-making/)

Comment: Did you make a question on Vim site? Can you link it?

Comment: [Also posted at the vi site](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7323/51)

Answer (score 6):

You can also jump to a line directly with `(linenum)G`, high precision, fast. Combine that with`H` for top of screen, `M` for middle of screen, `L` for end of screen. `gg` for top of document, `G` for bottom of document, and the `{` `}` you mentioned already.

Comment: Moving vertically knowing the line number is an option, definitely!  But as i mention in my question, i would like an alternative.  There should be many ways of doing the same thing in Vim, right?

Comment: Remembered there's also `(num of lines)`+`j`&`k`. I find when I need to move quickly, most of the time I have a pattern in mind, search `/pattern` and jump back and forth with `N` & `n`

Comment: `:set nonu rnu` lets you visualize relative line numbers, which help you to use `(count) j` or `(count) k`

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I use C-f and C-b to go page up and down, / and ? to do search (very rarely) and I use [ and ] commands from vim-unimpaired script quite a lot to move around code.